Rudin's PMA Exercise 2.7 (b) example verification
Part (b) second half:
Let $A_1, A_2, A_3,$ ... be subsets of a metric space.
Let $B = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$, find an example of proper inclusion:
$$\overline{B} \supset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \overline{A_i}$$
My example:
Set each $A_i = \{(x,i)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | x\in[4,7]\}$. So each $A_i$ is a horizontal line segment from $x=4$ to $x=7$, with $y=i$. Then each $\overline{A_i}=A_i$, so this is a rectangle $$\bigcup\limits_{i\in[0,1)} \overline{A_i} = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x\in[4,7], y\in[0,1)\}$$.
Meanwhile $\overline{B}$, the closure of the union of all $A_i$, would be the slightly wider rectangle:
$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x\in[4,7], y\in[0,1]\}$$
My concern is that Rudin's definition of $B$ requires iteration to be over the positive integers instead of an infinite set of real numbers...

What is your question?

In your definition of the set $A_i$ for each $i$, use a convergent sequence, e.g.,
$$
A_i := \bigl\{(x,y_i)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid x\in[4,7]\bigr\}, 
$$
with $y_i = \frac1i$. Now,
$$
B = [4, 7] \times \bigl\{1, \tfrac12, \tfrac13, \dots\bigr\}, 
$$
and since $\displaystyle\smash{\lim_{i\to\infty} y_i} = 0$,
the closure $\overline{B}$ contains the segment $[4, 7] \times \{0\}$ as well.
But the union of the closed intervals $\overline{A}_i = A_i$ does not include these points.

Note: this is not a rectangle, but rather a collection of line segments that get closer to one another as they approach the axis. The closure of the union has points on the axis; whereas, the union of the closures does not.

You example is correct, it shows that if $B = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in J} A_\alpha$ with an infinite index set, then in general
$$\overline{B} \supsetneqq \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in J}\overline{A_\alpha} .$$
An easy example with a countable index set is this:
Let $q_1, q_2, q_3, \ldots$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers and $A_i = \{q_i\} \subset \mathbb R$. Then $\overline{A_i} = A_i$ so that
$$B = \mathbb Q = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty\overline{A_i} ,$$
$$\overline B = \mathbb R .$$

The example of the OP is not correct.

@jjagmath What is wrong in the OP's example?

OP is considering $A_i$ with $i\in [0,1)$ instead of a sequence of sets. That's actually the whole point of the question, the OP doubt about that, where OP says "My concern is that Rudin's definition of $B$
requires iteration to be over the positive integers ..."
